# CREATE TABLE only user in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to create user that can create only tables in database?

grant create on database sport to test1; is wrong because we can create triggers too

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that except with an event trigger that throws an error whenever the wrong user creates certain objects.

Note that creating tables or triggers is not connected to permissions on the database, but to permissions on the schema. It seems strange and arbitrary to me to prevent a user that can create tables from adding triggers to these tables.